# Rearranging a variable size list by an inputted positions

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I need some advice on how to rearrange a list of names like, `["A", "B", "C", "D"]`, using an inputted order of positions like, `[3,1,4,2]`.

The problem is that the size of the name list is variable from `1` to `4` and the positions are also variable, based on an input. Their length is the same, so when there are 3 names, there are 3 values in the positions.

In the basic non-rearranged list of names `["A", "B", "C", "D"]`, the position of the values: `A is 1, B is 2` and so on.

**Example:** non-rearranged names are ["Mat", "Bara", "Tom"] so Mat is 1, Bara is 2, Tom is 3

**Example:** new positions should be [3,1,2]

**Example:** rearranged list would be ["Tom","Mat","Bara"]

So far I have tried things like `names[positions[i]]` and a handful of other things, but no luck.

this is the very simple code so far:

```
num = 0
pos_list = []
name_list = []

num = int(input("how many names:"))
for i in range(num):
    name = input("input name:")
    name_list.append(name)
    pos = int(input("enter the positions that the names should be arranged to:"))
    pos_list.append(pos)

# first name entered is 1, the second name entered is 2 so on...
# now they have to be rearranged by the inputted positions
```

Any advice appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
names_list = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
pos_list = [3,1,4,2]
print([names_list[i-1] for i in pos_list])
# ['C', 'A', 'D', 'B']
```

Comment: Hi Timur, thanks soooo much:), I was obviously overcomplicating it for myself. Thanks a huge lot, have an awesome day:)